# Trying to set cookie on page load (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, cookies, widget

I am trying to set a cookie when the page loads with a number taken from user input in the back end of a widget and I can't seem to get it work.

Here is my simplified code:

```
class my_class extends WP_Widget {

## get variable from the backend form settings of widget
  function form($instance) {
  global $instance;
  $title = ! empty( $instance['variableiwant'] ) ? $instance['title'] : __( 'variableiwant' );
    }

    ##update save of widget
    function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['variableiwant'] = strip_tags($new_instance[ 'variableiwant']);
        return $instance;   
    }

    function widget($args, $instance) {
    }

##here I try and set the cookie from the backend variable before headers are sent.

function set_newuser_cookie() {
global $instance;
global $variableiwant;

if (isset($_COOKIE["variablesave"]))
          ;
      else
      {
        setcookie("variablesave", $variableiwant, time()+3600);
    }
}

add_action( 'send_headers', 'set_newuser_cookie');
```

Now the problem I have is the cookie can only be set before the headers are sent, I have tried other hooks before "send_headers" but nothing works. Obviously if you add the hook after the headers it throws an error saying "warning headers already sent" is there a way to grab that variable from the backend input and set it as a cookie before the headers are sent? I've tried everything and nothing seems to work the cookie is simply set as NULL.

Comment: your `if` statement is a little weird. better to use `!isset()` and drop the `else`.

Comment: And try hooking to the `init` action, it should fire early enough to set a cookie.

Comment: I tried the init action already it still doesnt seem to capture the variable before the headers are sent. From what I can see it seems thats no matter what, the function form where it gets the variable from the backend of the widget isn't actioned before the headers are sent, the variable still is set to NULL

Comment: Having this same issue in 2018 and can't find a solution anywhere.

Comment: @BadHorsie Having the same issue in late 2019 and can't find a solution...